# Correct Verb/Preposition Choice - Impute For

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, word-meaning, verbs

To impute means to to lay the responsibility or blame for (something) often falsely or unjustly. I tried to use this in a sentence:

> Even the obsequious guy who imputed Sam for violent behavior said sorry to him.

Is this sentence correct? I checked on multiple websites but I could not find its usage in the form of **imputed for**. Almost everywhere it was **imputed to**. Isn't its meaning similar to the verb **blame**?

Comment: You impute _something_ to _someone_ e.g. The guy who imputed violent behaviour to Sam. This is explained in the Cambridge Dictionary. Your suggested usage is an error.

Comment: @Micheal Harvey...Can I contact you somewhere? Actually I try to make a paragraph everyday with the vocabulary I learn and proofreading questions are not allowed on the website. Can you please help me.

Comment: Private links and messaging are not encouraged here.

Comment: I am not a teacher, and such solicitations are strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*to impute* takes a direct object (the 'something' you mentioned) and an indirect object, often a person, specified by 'to', so the following would be correct:

> Even the obsequious guy who imputed violent behavior to Sam said sorry to him.

This follows the many example sentences mentioned [here in Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/impute).